# drop down list databind with new item inserted in detailsview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On my page I have two object data sources;

the first has a bound drop downlist, with an item number and a description. 
 The second has a bound details view showing everything for the item number.

Selecting an item in the drop down list, causes the details to be shown, as
intended. When I insert a new record from the details view, I want to add it
to the drop down list and select it.

I tried to just do a:

```
Private Sub dvRecipeItem_ItemInserted(sender As Object, e As DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs) Handles dvRecipeItem.ItemInserted
    ddRecipeItemNumber.DataBind()
End Sub
```

And even though Databind does load the newly added item to the drop down list, it does not make it the selected value, thus the record displayed on the details view is just whichever item number is first since it is ordered by item number

can some one explain me how to make it work for the scenario i described on the second paragraph?

thank you very much.

```
<asp:DropDownList 
ID="ddRecipeItemNumber" 
runat="server" 
width="600px" 
DataSourceID="EntityDataSource_RecipeItemNumber" 
DataTextField="DisplayName" 
DataValueField="Id" 
AutoPostBack="True"
OnDataBinding="Page_Load"
CssClass="cssRecipeItemNumber">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:EntityDataSource 
ID="EntityDataSource_RecipeItemNumber" 
runat="server" 
ConnectionString="name=OLTPEntities" 
DefaultContainerName="OLTPEntities" 
EnableFlattening="False" 
EntitySetName="vStd_RefineRecipe" 
EnableDelete="True" 
EnableInsert="True" 
EnableUpdate="True" 
EntityTypeFilter="vStd_RefineRecipe" 
Where="It.Id > 0"
OrderBy="It.ItemNumber">
</asp:EntityDataSource>

<asp:DetailsView 
ID="dvRecipeItem" 
runat="server" 
AutoGenerateRows="False"
DataKeyNames="Id" 
DataSourceID="EntityDataSource_RecipeItemDetail" 
OnItemCommand="dvRecipeItem_ItemCommandEventHandler"
GridLines="None" 
HeaderText="Recipe Detail"
CssClass="cssDetailsView"
HeaderStyle-CssClass="header"
Font-Names="Arial,Sans-Serif"
Font-Size="11px"
AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alternating"
CommandRowStyle-CssClass="command"
FieldHeaderStyle-CssClass="fieldheader">
<Fields>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" InsertVisible="False">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label_Id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Id" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label_Id" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Number" SortExpression="ItemNumber">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_ItemNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemNumber") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_ItemNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemNumber") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label_ItemNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True" InsertText="Insert" UpdateText="Update" DeleteText="Delete" />                                
    </Fields>                            
    </asp:DetailsView>
    <asp:EntityDataSource 
        ID="EntityDataSource_RecipeItemDetail" 
        runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="name=OLTPEntities" 
        DefaultContainerName="OLTPEntities" 
        EnableFlattening="False" 
        EntitySetName="RefineRecipe" 
        Where="it.Id = @RecipeId" 
        EnableDelete="True" 
        EnableInsert="True" 
        EnableUpdate="True" 
        EntityTypeFilter="RefineRecipe">
        <WhereParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter 
        ControlID="ddRecipeItemNumber" 
        DbType="Int32" 
        DefaultValue="1" 
        Name="RecipeId" 
        PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </WhereParameters>
        </asp:EntityDataSource>

Private Sub dvRecipeItem_ItemInserted(sender As Object, e As      DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs) Handles dvRecipeItem.ItemInserted

ddRecipeItemNumber.DataBind()
ddRecipeItemNumber.Items.FindByValue(DirectCast(dvRecipeItem.FindControl("TextBox_ItemNumber"), TextBox).Text).Selected = True

End Sub
```

Comment: where are the dvRecipeItem in html file

Answer (score 0):

Wirte Code This Way::

```
Private Sub dvRecipeItem_ItemInserted(sender As Object, e As DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs) Handles dvRecipeItem.ItemInserted

    ddRecipeItemNumber.DataBind()
    ddRecipeItemNumber.Items.FindByValue(e.Values["ItemNumber"].ToString()).Selected = true;

End Sub
```

*String val is a your newly insert string

Comment: not sure how to do that. this is the insert Template
<InsertItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_ItemNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemNumber") %>'></asp:TextBox>                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="TextBox_ItemNumber"                                             runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Please enter an Item Number"                                             ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                                    </InsertItemTemplate>

Comment: should I replace (string val) with: TextBox_ItemNumber

Comment: replace with any string that are in the dropdownlist

Comment: refer this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.insertitemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: i did this too:
ddRecipeItemNumber.DataBind()
ddRecipeItemNumber = CType(dvRecipeItem.FindControl("TextBox_ItemNumber"), DropDownList)

got an error:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'.

Comment: ddRecipeItemNumber.Items.FindByValue(CType(dvRecipeItem.FindControl("TextBox_ItemNumber"), TextBox).Text).Selected = true;

Comment: i tried your recommendation and also this way:
ddRecipeItemNumber.Items.FindByValue(DirectCast(dvRecipeItem.FindControl("TextBox_ItemNumber"), TextBox).Text).Selected = True

Comment: for both I get  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I added the code on the question. the drop down list and its entity source, the template field, and the sub

Comment: where are the dvRecipeItem in html file

Comment: i put all the aspx code for the details view, just removed some extra fields that were not necessary to show. thank you

Comment: try This :     ddRecipeItemNumber.Items.FindByValue(e.Values["ItemNumber"].ToString()).Selected = true;

Comment: ddRecipeItemNumber.Items.FindByValue(e.Values["ItemNumber"].ToString()).Selected = true; This is your lat line....